# how to get all object coordinates in canvas wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new in wpf,I want such a thing to be done : I have rectangle and I'm dragging and dropping it in the canvas so they would become multiple. so after pressing some button, how can I get x coordinate of each rectangle dropped on my canvas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate through the `Children` collection of the `Canvas` and use the `Canvas.GetLeft` method to get the X coordinate within the Canvas of each child element:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Rectangle rect in canvas.Children.OfType<Rectangle>())
    {
        double x = Canvas.GetLeft(rect);
        double y = Canvas.GetTop(rect);
    }
}
```

---

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas">
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" />
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="20" />
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="30" />
</Canvas>
```